# using aggregate in R when returning matrix

Tags: python, r, function, matrix, apply

I want to use aggregate to apply some manipulations to a set of matrices, grouped by the `customer_id`, which is one column of my dataframe, `df`.

For example, I want to take the subsets of `df` that correspond to different `customer_id`'s and add some columns to these subsets, and return them all.

In Python, I would use groupby and apply.

How can I do this in R?

The code I wrote looks like:

```
gr_TILPS = aggregate(df,by=list(df[,"customer_id"]),FUN=kmeansfunction)

Error in TILPSgroup$hour : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

The error is coming from the kmeansfunction I guess, which looks something like:

```
kmeansfunction = function(dfgroup){

Hour =dfgroup$hour
Weekday =TILPSgroup$WeekdayPrime
x <- cbind(Hour, Weekday)
colnames(x) <- c("x", "y")
(cl <- kmeans(x, 2))
clusters = cl$cluster
origclusters = as.factor(clusters)
dfgroup = cbind(dfgroup,origclusters)

return(dfgroup)
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`aggregate` applies the same function to multiple *single* columns. If you want to work on  ensembles of columns, then use this paradigm: `lapply(split(df,group),function)`;

Try this:

```
gr_TILPS <- lapply( split(df, df[,"customer_id"]),
                    FUN=kmeansfunction)
```

Sounds like python might have some similarities to the experimental package: 'dplyr'. In a sense `aggregate` is only a column-oriented processing strategy within blocks, while the `lapply(split, ), )` strategy is more applicable when you are interested in entire rows of data, defined by a blocking criterion. If you later want to row-bind those results back together you can always use `do.call(rbind, res_from_lapply)`.